# Renaming file from a script?

Tags: scripting, rename

I am creating a script which would enable me do something in a shorter amount of time. Is there a way that I can rename a file automatically from:

```
WDMyCloud_plexmediaserver_1.16.1.1291.bin(07082019)'
```

to

```
WDMyCloud_plexmediaserver_1.16.1.1291.bin
```

So it would detect the numbers, but would delete the part after `.bin`.

I am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `mv`:

```
file='WDMyCloud_plexmediaserver_1.16.1.1291.bin(07082019)'
mv "$file" "${file%.bin*}.bin"
```

Use `prename` or `file-rename` (in Debian/Ubuntu also known as just `rename`):

```
prename -n 's/\.bin.*$/.bin/' WDMyCloud_plexmediaserver_1.16.1.1291.bin\(07082019\)
```

Remove the `-n` to actually perform the rename.

Comment: Rename is not working it shows a proper new filename, but doesn't rename it in the end. Any chance of getting it right, because it would be the best solution? Version number of the filename is something that changes, so mv doesn't work. WDMyCloud_plexmediaserver is fixed. I basically just want to get rid of the last part which could work for any version number. Thank you!

Comment: Sry, forgot to say. Remove the -n to actually perform the rename.

Comment: Perfect. I've used: rename -n 's/\.bin.*$/.bin/' WDMyCloud_plexmediaserver_*.bin\(*\) and it's working perfectly. Thank you! I now have to use only one script file.

Answer (score 0):

You can create script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i
do
mv "$i" "${i%\(*}"
done
```

Now you can pass the filenames as arguments to this script provided this script is in same folder with all files.

e.g.

```
file 'WDMyCloud_plexmediaserver_1.16.1.1291.bin(07082019)' 'WDMyCloud_plexmediaserver_1.16.1.1292.bin(07082011)'
```

Will be renamed in the same folder as

```
WDMyCloud_plexmediaserver_1.16.1.1291.bin
WDMyCloud_plexmediaserver_1.16.1.1292.bin
```

Comment: Solution worked, but had to create another script outside of my file to run it. Thank you.

Comment: @LaMplR if you don't want to pass argument to file then replace that `for` loop with `for i in WDMyCloud_plexmediaserver_*.bin(*)`. Passing arguments are helpful if you don't want to rename every file matching the pattern.